# My custom post type is not showing for the yith_vendor user roles

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have developed Offers for WooCommerce plugin. Now we want to make an extension which shows all offers of products owns by the vendors created by YITH multi vendors plugin. So the issue is that if I register with vendors I don't see my custom post type "manage offers" even I assign all the capabilities to that user role or users. Can you please help me how I can allow access to my custom post type for the users with vendor role? It shows me error "Invalid post type." for vendor role.

Here is the plugin we have developed: https://wordpress.org/plugins/offers-for-woocommerce/

We want to create extension for https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-vendors/

Here is the code for registering custom post type:

```
add_action('init', array( $this, 'angelleye_ofwc_add_post_type_woocommerce_offer' ) );

function angelleye_ofwc_add_post_type_woocommerce_offer(){
    $show_in_menu = current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ? 'woocommerce' : true;
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Manage Offers', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'singular_name' => __('WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'edit' => __('Manage', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'edit_item' => __('Manage WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'new_item' => __('New WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'view' => __('View', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'view_item' => __('View WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'search_items' => __('Search WooCommerce Offers', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'not_found' => __('No WooCommerce Offers found', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No WooCommerce Offers found in Trash', 'offers-for-woocommerce'),
            'parent' => __('Parent WooCommerce Offer', 'offers-for-woocommerce')
        ),
        'description' => 'Offers for WooCommerce - Custom Post Type',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,            
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'show_in_menu' => $show_in_menu,
        'menu_position' => '',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'section_id_offer_comments', 'section_id_offer_summary', 'section_id_offer_addnote' ),
        'taxonomies' => array(''),
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'woocommerce_offer',
        'map_meta_cap' => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'woocommerce_offer', $args );

    $this->create_woocommerce_offer_capabilities();
}

public function create_woocommerce_offer_capabilities() {
    global $wp_roles;

    $woocommerce_offer_capabilities = get_option('woocommerce_offer_capabilities');

    if (empty($woocommerce_offer_capabilities)) {

        if (!class_exists('WP_Roles')) {
            return;
        }

        if (!isset($wp_roles)) {
            $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
        }

        $capabilities = $this->get_core_capabilities();

        foreach ($capabilities as $cap_group) {
            foreach ($cap_group as $cap) {
                $wp_roles->add_cap('shop_manager', $cap); // allows access to shop managers
                $wp_roles->add_cap('administrator', $cap); // allows access to admins
                $wp_roles->add_cap('yith_vendor', $cap); //allows access to vendors of yith multi vendor plugin
            }
        }
    } else {
        update_option('woocommerce_offer_capabilities', true);
    }
}

public function get_core_capabilities() {
    $capabilities = array();

    $capability_types = array('woocommerce_offer');

    foreach ($capability_types as $capability_type) {

        $capabilities[$capability_type] = array(
            // Post type
            "edit_{$capability_type}",
            "read_{$capability_type}",
            "delete_{$capability_type}",
            "edit_{$capability_type}s",
            "edit_others_{$capability_type}s",
            "publish_{$capability_type}s",
            "read_private_{$capability_type}s",
            "delete_{$capability_type}s",
            "delete_private_{$capability_type}s",
            "delete_published_{$capability_type}s",
            "delete_others_{$capability_type}s",
            "edit_private_{$capability_type}s",
            "edit_published_{$capability_type}s",
        );
    }

    return $capabilities;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code samples of what you've tried that isn't working..??

Comment: I have provided the code to register custom post types and capabilities and assign those capabilities to shop managers, admins and vendors.